# How to split a string by "," except between certain characters in python?

Tags: python, split

How to split a string by "," except between certain characters in python?
My data is like:

```
('00012+1357','LSC   2','Aa,Ab',2014,2014,   2,185,185,  0.2,  0.2,10.7,13.1,'M0.5',+019,+135,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'000113.19+135830.3')
```

I need to split them by "," except for *'Aa,Ab'*.

The result should be:

```
("00012+1357" "LSC   2" "Aa,Ab" "2014" "2014" "2" "185" "185" "0.2"  "0.2" "10.7" "13.1" "M0.5" "+019" "+135" "NULL" "NULL" "NULL" "NULL" "000113.19+135830.3")
```

Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I do, but what have *you* tried.

Comment: Your data looks like a tuple......what exactly are you trying to do? `join`?

Comment: Is this data a `string` or a `list`?

Comment: If it is a `list` you can try something like this: `' '.join(map(str,data))`

Comment: when I split it by "," it splits all the data and as it is from a huge database, the code stops at this line. I couldn't find any command for this special line.

Comment: There is no NULL in Python. Please show your _actual_ data.

Comment: @FarzanehZohrabi you need to provide a minimum code example so we can understand what you're trying to do and help you.

Comment: I'm reading a SQL file on python that's why it has NULL in it. I have to make 20 columns from it. The code stops at line 90 out of 141000 lines and the problem is that "," in one of the strings.
the sql codes are like : 
INSERT INTO WDS VALUES ('00000+4004','ES 2543','AB   ',1931,2014,   5,252,253,  4.8,  4.2,12.1,13.1,NULL,+008,-004,-011,-002,NULL,NULL,'000003.66+400519.4');

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are looking for ''.join():

```
the_string = ('00012+1357','LSC   2','Aa,Ab',2014,2014,   2,185,185,  0.2,  0.2,10.7,13.1,'M0.5', 19, 135, 'NULL','NULL','NULL','NULL','000113.19+135830.3')

the_string = map(str, the_string)

new_string = (' '.join(i for i in the_string))
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're trying to parse CSV data. The [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module should be more than sufficient and be able to handle all these edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a stab at some code.
Splits a string by `needle` if it's outside `quotes`.
Assumes both `needle` and `quotes` are one character long.

```
#!python3

def splitExceptBetween(istr, needle, quotes):
    inside = -1
    res = []
    oldt = 0
    for index, letter in enumerate(istr):
        if letter==quotes:
            inside = -inside
        elif letter==needle and inside == -1:
            res.append(istr[oldt:index])
            oldt = index+1
    if oldt<len(istr):
        res.append(istr[oldt:])
    return res

istr = "as'das'd.asdas'd.a'sdas.drth..rt'h.r'th.'"
print(splitExceptBetween(istr, ".", "'"))
istr = "00012+1357,LSC   2,'Aa,Ab',2014,2014,   2,185,185,  0.2,  0.2,10.7,13.1,M0.5,+019,+135,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,000113.19+135830.3"
print(splitExceptBetween(istr, ",", "'"))
```